# How to put the text in the box?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, how do I put the following text in the box?

---

[image]

```css
body {
  background: rgb(246, 249, 250);
  color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  font-family: "PingFang SC", "Helvetica Neue", "Microsoft 
 YaHei", Arial, sans-serif;

}

.say {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1.16667rem;
}

.con {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(209, 209, 209);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0px 8px 8px;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  height: 3.5rem;
}

img {
  height: 2.9rem;
  width: 2.9rem;
}

.txt {
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.16667rem;
  width: calc(100% - 3.7rem);
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.txt p:nth-child(2) {
  color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="say">
    <p>Download now!</p>
    <p>No need of mobile data!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="con">
    <div class="list">
      <div class="use">
        <img src="icon.png" alt="icon">
        <div class="txt">
          <p>SMA205F</p>
          <p>shared 0 files</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also add respective html.

Comment: Don't add code in the comment. Instead, edit your question and include and properly format it there.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Could you add the relevant HTML code to your question so we can help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body{
  background: rgb(246, 249, 250);
  color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  font-family: "PingFang SC", "Helvetica Neue", "Microsoft 
  YaHei", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.say{
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  line-height: 1.16667rem;
}

.con{
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(209, 209, 209);
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0px 8px 8px;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  height: 3.5rem;
}

img{
  height: 2.9rem;
  width: 2.9rem;
}

.txt{
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.16667rem;
  width: calc(100% - 3.7rem);
  margin-left: 4rem;
}

.txt p:nth-child(2){
  color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
}

.use{display: flex;}
p{margin: 0}
```

```html
<div class="box"> 
  <div class="say"> 
  <p>Download now!</p> 
  <p>No need of mobile data!</p> 
  </div> 
  
  <div class="con"> 
    <div class="list"> 
    <div class="use"> 
    <img src="icon.png" alt="icon"> 
          <div class="txt"> 
          <p>SMA205F</p> 
          <p>shared 0 files</p> 
          </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```